# Fetch messages filtered by conversationId via Office365 API

Tags: outlook, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use the office365 api to fetch messages given a `conversationId`.

Let's say my conversationId is `AAQkADlkOGJmMTFmLTc2NjMtMKL3My04ZDhkLTVmZWNjMzA1ODY0NAAQAB11Xh2opSpBiXifMEJjhow=`

I'll make a request like

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/Messages?$filter=ConversationId%20eq%20AAQkADlkOGJmMTFmLTc2NjMtMKL3My04ZDhkLTVmZWNjMzA1ODY0NAAQAB11Xh2opSpBiXifMEJjhow=
```

This results in a `400` response like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "RequestBroker-ParseUri",
    "message": "Syntax error at position 98 in 'ConversationId eq AAQkADlkOGJmMTFmLTc2NjMtMKL3My04ZDhkLTVmZWNjMzA1ODY0NAAQAB11Xh2opSpBiXifMEJjhow='."
  }
}
```

I tried other things, such as url encoding the conversationId to `AAQkADlkOGJmMTFmLTc2NjMtMKL3My04ZDhkLTVmZWNjMzA1ODY0NAAQAB11Xh2opSpBiXifMEJjhow%3D` which results in the same error.

I also tried simply removing the `=` which seems to be the character that is freaking it out

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/Messages?$filter=ConversationId%20eq%20AAQkADlkOGJmMTFmLTc2NjMtMKL3My04ZDhkLTVmZWNjMzA1ODY0NAAQAB11Xh2opSpBiXifMEJjhow
```

but that results in the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "RequestBroker-ParseUri",
    "message": "Could not find a property named 'AAQkADlkOGJmMTFmLTc2NjMtMKL3My04ZDhkLTVmZWNjMzA1ODY0NAAQAB11Xh2opSpBiXifMEJjhow' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'."
  }
}
```

I've also tried messing with the url capitalization and using `+` signs instead of `%20` for the filter string, but I consistently get 400 errors back.

I am able to filter by other fields though. For example

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/Messages?$filter=IsRead%20eq%20true
```

returns messages filtered as I would expect.

Any idea what could be going on with the `ConversationId` filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the `ConversationId` with single quotes.
This is how I forge my request in C#

```
string finalUrl = "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/Messages?$filter=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Format("ConversationId eq '{0}'", conversationId));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to my question - but I have a follow up. Currently using that filter I get 0 results even though it's a real conversationId. So I can fetch a message which has my conversationId, but when I filter by conversationId the message is not returned. Do you happen to have a solution or explanation for that?

Comment: 1) you sure the authentication bearer is for the mailbox with this `ConversationId` ? 2) Can you try with an updated version of the api e.g. v2 or beta ?