# Email thread detection in an Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, add-in, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm designing an Outlook add-in and need to determine whether a selected message is part of a thread. Ideally, I'd also like to find related messages in said thread as well. Reading over the [documentation](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/index.html), the [conversationId](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html#conversationId) property looks promising, though there doesn't seem to be a way to "get messages by conversationId."

Under the current version (1.4, non-preview) of the Outlook Add-in API, is it possible to detect that a message is part of a thread using the JavaScript API? Is it possible to then *find* other messages in the same thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `ConversationId` is part of the javascript API. This means that you can know the `ConversationId` for the `Office.context.mailbox.item` whose your add-in is focusing on. See [documentation here](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html#conversationId)
- To my knowledge, there is no way to retrieve all mails for a given `ConversationId` using vanilla javascript and Office.js.

However, you may be interested in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768988/how-to-get-recurrence-data-from-javascript-api-in-office365/35770085#35770085).

> When something is not available with Office.js api for an Outlook
>   Add-in you can try to use the Exchange Web Services (EWS) or REST APIs to  perform the action

You have basically two ways to request EWS from a mail add-in.

> - You can request directly the EWS with a SOAP request from your client
>     app. See method makeEwsRequestAsync in Office.context.mailbox(https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html).
> - You can get an access token, send it to your server and make the request from
>     there.

For the specific case of retrieving conversations using the Outlook REST API, [this answer may also be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161515/best-way-to-achieve-conversation-view-for-mail-folder-using-outlook-rest-api).

Comment: The fact that conversationId is documented in the 1.4 API documentation (https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html#conversationId) means that it's part of the JavaScript API, no? Seems odd for it not to be. +1 on the EWS suggestion; I think even if conversationId is what I think it is, I'd still have to leverage EWS to get the related messages.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not check the documentation on 1.4... my bad. I keep the answer because it may be useful for others. So what you are looking for is not retrieving the conversationID of a mail but all mail to this thread. You may be interested by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125652/fetch-messages-filtered-by-conversationid-via-office365-api/41131045#41131045

Comment: please update your answer to A. reflect that conversationId is part of the JavaScript API and that B. there is not (yet) a native JavaScript API hook for retrieving related messages, and I'll accept your answer.